# pip install theanets fails an error

Tags: python-3.x

When you run the command 'pip install theanets', it's fine:

> Collecting theanets
>    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/58/67329f5da252c282adb915a705e8c34be0a964cfbe7b43a2320103dd1a46/theanets-0.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting climate (from theanets)

and it disguises the error:

> Could not find a version that meets the climate (from theanets) (from versions:)
>   No matching distribution found for climate (from theanets)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like climate is not available on PyPI and a new version of theanets hasn't been released to remove the dependency (though it looks like master may have removed it).

Answer (score 0):

download the current source and run it from there:

```
git clone http://github.com/lmjohns3/theanets 
cd theanets
python setup.py develop
```